# I need to have dependent drop down lists in my google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have gone through many formulas, scripts, and functions but still not solved. If anybody can provide me the script or suggest me a best add on for this then it will really pleasure for me.Note. I want to insert dependent drop down lists in Columns D & E, D= Battery Name & E= Battery Type and when we select battery name then it shows the relevant categories types of selected battery name.Thanks, Stay blessed.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_a4jA1UD-QgzxD7Y-I-6swGqXPjm-R-O8dMTEYV-rk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see this is your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers. Note that StackOverflow is not a coding service, we won't work out your assignments.

Comment: Not really clear on what you what to do? Something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYcZU1UzTmE

Comment: Hi, No this is not like that its simple and straight like I have different batteries types under a Battery name and I want that when I select the battery name then it shows me only the battery types dependent on battery name. The reason to put the question here is that the google recomends me that if you still not get your answer then you may also try these forums in which stackoverflow.com included.